# PHP symlink(): Permission denied in writeable folder

Tags: php, symlink, permission-denied

I want to create a symlink with PHP.

The symlink needs to go in the same place as the uploaded file, which should be fine right?

My real problem is that when using `symlink()`, I get a permission denied error on the same directory that PHP can write to from `$_FILES`.

I have done a test using `text.txt` as the test file, and `link` as the symlink:

`symlink("repository/text.txt", "link");`

The PHP script is run from `content/folder/script.php`. What am I doing wrong here? Do symlinks need file extensions (I doubt it) or something?

Comment: If you did not specify absolute path for `link`, PHP will use the current working directory, is this what your want?

Comment: Yeah that was my problem - please see goreSplatter's post below :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the code you're using

```
symlink("repository/text.txt", "link");
```

And your script runs as `/var/www/scripts/script.php` the symlink will be created in the directory the script runs in.

Try using an absolute path.

Comment: Thanks :-) that worked great. The problem was that the second argument (`link`) was relative, not absolute, just as you said. All fixed now with `symlink("repository/file.txt", "repository/link");`